# Redirect traffic to www. domain using Amazon Route 53

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I know this question has been asked a lot, not only in this forum, but unfortunately none of the cases are applicable to my scenario.

So in my case, I have a domain (example.de) at Strato.de and my web app running in AWS Elastic Beanstalk.

Now I have created a hosted zone in AWS Route 53 and put all 4 Name Servers into strato.de backend. It worked and I can reach my site under:
meyn-computer-lotse.de

The problem is if you try to reach it with www.meyn-computer-lotse.de you get an error.

I tried to set up a S3 bucket, like it is explained in this article: https://www.webmaster-zentrale.de/hosting/amazon-route-53-richtig-bedienen/

So the buckets name was meyn-computer-lotse.de (without wwww) and I granted public read access and redirected to www.meyn-computer-lotse.de.

Then I added a record set in AWS Route 53 for the name www.meyn-computer-lotse and the Alias of the bucket.

It doesn't work and I need the website running under wwww.meyn-computer-lotse.de.

Should I had created a hosted zone under www.meyn-computer-lotse.de and then use the 4 Name Servers from that zone?

Help is really much appreciated!

**EDIT:**
I followed the steps from this question and this all works, but not the www. redirect. [Route 53 with external Domain Registrar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45064245/route-53-with-external-domain-registrar/45064339?noredirect=1#comment91802482_45064339)

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell what could be the issue since it seems you are doing the right thing. However I will describe the steps bellow and you can double check yours.

- I would suggest you to create a bucket with the exactly name of your website. Why? Because it will appear under the "S3 website endpoints" when you create your recordset in router 53.
- You set your bucket to be a static web host. Properties >> Static website hosting >> Use this bucket to host a website
- Then in route 53 create a new recordset and select Type: A - IPv4 address, alias: yes and then the alias target will suggest you the S3 bucket you create (you just select it). If it does not suggest the S3 bucket, just refresh your page.
- If you want to have an http and/or your page is a SPA you have to create an AWS cloudfront. * if this is the case, let me know and I can give more details on this one.

-- EDIT --

If you are creating a recordset for your an application deployed with elasticbeanstalk, you dont have to do anything with your bucket.

- Under amazon services, select elasticbeanstalk, then copy the URL of your application.
- Then you go to S3 and create your  www.meyn-computer-lotse.de recordset which you fill the CNAME with the URL.

Comment: Hey, first of all thanks for your reply!

The problem is my website is not static. It is build with python-django and I uploaded it with ElasticBeanstalk, this created a bucket on its own, but the name is not my domain. Or do you mean I should create an empty bucket with the name www.meyn-computer-lotse.de?

Comment: No worries mate. What do you mean it is not static and you are hosting it on S3? The bucket should be used only for static websites.
The answer to your question is yes, because you should have a bucket with the same name of your recordset. Then when you upload the files, you should inform the bucket name s3://www.meyn-computer-lotse.de

Dont forget to setup the permissions as public.

Comment: With not static I mean, I did not upload bunch of hmtl files into a S3 bucket but I uploaded a django zip file into the EC2 environment and then Amazon has created a bucket on its own, but I haven't and will not touch that bucket and the name of that bucket is something with "elasticbeanstalk-eu-central....." I have successfully redirected www.meyn-computer-lotse.de to meyn-computer-lotse.de temprarily.

Comment: Im sorry I didnt understand your problem properly. What confused me was the fact that you are trying to manage the bucket (using an article). You dont have to do that.

Under amazon services, select elasticbeanstalk, then select the URL of your application.
The you go to S3 and create your  www.meyn-computer-lotse.de recordset which you fill the CNAME with the URL.

Comment: Thanks and I'm sorry for any confusions caused by me! So you mean to create bucket with the name www.meyn-computer-lotse.de and then under properties fill in the redirect to the URL of my beanstalk environment? Or do you mean a new recordset in Route 53?

Comment: Just a new recordset